# Finding document by numeric fields in Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

For example, I have some documents described by fields: `id`, `date` and `price`.

First document: `id=1`, `date='from 10.01.2014 to 20.01.2014'`, `price='120'`

Second document: `id=2`, `date='19.01.2014'` and `price='from 100 to 140'`

My program receives key/value parameters and should find the most suitable documents. So, for example, with this parameters `date=19.01.2014` and `price='120'` program should find both documents. With `date=20.01.2014`, `price=120'` only the first document. With `date='19.01.2014`, `price=140'` only the second one.

How can I do it with Lucene in Java? I saw examples where I'm typing query like 'give me docs where date is from .. to ..', and Lucene gives me docs in this range. Instead of this I want to specify range for my document and not for query.

Answer (score 1):

You could index both opening and closing ranges for dates and prices, e.g.

Your document #1 would be indexed as:

```
id = 1
dateFrom = 10.01.2014 
dateTo = 20.01.2014 
priceFrom = 120
priceTo = 9999999999
```

And document #2 as

```
id=2
dateFrom = 19.01.2014
dateTo = 01.01.2099
priceFrom = 100
priceTo = 140
```

The query would look like this:

```
+dateFrom:[19.01.2014 TO *] +priceFrom:[120 TO *] +priceTo:[* TO 140]
```

This is not very effective but it should work.

Comment: I think it might work if nothing else will be found. Thank you.